# Is recitation of Selichot a halachic obligation?

Tags: halacha, selichot

Is recitation of Selichot a halachic obligation?

I'm not asking if it's "only d'rabbanan", as rabbinic laws also create halachic obligations.

At the same time, not every custom that is mentioned in rabbinic writings is obligatory.

Comment: It's sounds like you are thinking of "halachic obligation" in a very specific way. As you know this term can have a variety of connotations so I encourage you to be as specific as possible regarding exactly what kind of connotation you are using.

Comment: @Jake, what is "a halachic obligation"?

Comment: A halachic obligation is something that a Jew is obligated to do, according to Jewish law.  This is in contrast to a minhag, which might be "good", "nice", or even "advisable", but not obligatory.

Comment: That's not how I would have used the terms, but OK. As long as you're clear and consistent.

Answer (score 4):

Selichot cannot be a Halachic Obligation (as defined by you as *something that a Jew is obligated to do, according to Jewish law. This is in contrast to a minhag, which might be "good", "nice", or even "advisable", but not obligatory*).

The reason is that - as the Tur mentions in תקפ"א - that it was instituted by the Geonim and Rishonim. So until about 1,000 years ago nobody had ever heard of this *obligation*.

The Shulchan Aruch clearly calls it a Minhag - not an obligation - in סימן תקפא - דיני ימי תחנונים וערב ראש השנה.

> **...א:** **נוֹהֲגִים** לָקוּם  בְּאַשְׁמֹרֶת לוֹמַר סְלִיחוֹת וְתַחֲנוּנִים ‏
>
> It's **customary** to say Selichot in the end of the night...

Not only isn't saying Selichot a halachic obligation, but some Poskim insist that they must **not** be said without a Minyan.

E.g. See the Remo in סימן תקסה - דין תפלת עננו who says אֵין לְיָחִיד לוֹמַר סְלִיחוֹת אוֹ  וַיַּעֲבֹר - an individual, i.e. without a Minya, one may not say Selichot or the 13 attributes.

Others argue that one should simply skip those Selichot that make mention the 13 attributes. The more lenient ones argue that the 13 attributes should be said as one reads the Torah, with the correct tune and trop.

In context:

> **ה:** אֵין הַיָּחִיד רַשַּׁאי לוֹמַר שְׁלֹשׁ עֶשְׂרֵה מִדּוֹת דֶּרֶךְ תְּפִלָּה וּבַקָּשַׁת רַחֲמִים, דְּדָבָר שֶׁבַּקְּדֻשָּׁה הֵם; אֲבָל אִם בָּא לְאָמְרָם דֶּרֶךְ *(ה)* קְרִיאָה בְּעָלְמָא, אוֹמְרָם.‏
>  **הגה**: *וְכֵן אֵין לְיָחִיד לוֹמַר סְלִיחוֹת אוֹ* (ו) *וַיַּעֲבֹר* (מַהֲרִי''ל בְּשֵׁם אוֹר זָרוּעַ). ‏
>
> **באר היטב**  *(ה) קריאה*. בניגון ובטעמים. כשאומר ויקרא בשם ה' יש להפסיק מעט בין שם לה'. אין לומר האדרת והאמונה בצבור כ''א ביה''כ. אין לומר קודם חצות לילה שום סליחה ולא י''ג מדות בשום פנים לעולם חוץ מביה''כ. אחרונים עיין מ''א:‏
> **באר היטב** *(ו*) ויעבור. כ' הב''ח זה אינו אלא משום ויעבור אבל סליחות ותחנונים בלא ויעבור אין איסור בדבר **אבל הט''ז כתב דאפי' סליחות בלא ויעבור אסור** משום שמזכיר בסליחות וזכור לנו היום ברית שלש עשרה וכן בהרבה סליחות שימצא י''ג מדות אותם אין לאומר' אפי' בלא ויעבור אבל אותם סליחות שאין נזכר בהם י''ג מדות ודאי יכול לאומרם ע''כ: ‏

Also, those Selichot written in Aramaic should not be said without a Minyan, as the Mishna Berurah says (תקפא ד)

> וכן אותם הבקשות שהן בלשון תרגום כגון מחי ומסי וכו' ומרן די בשמיא וכו' לא יאמר כשאין שם מנין עשרה. ‏

That said, since it's a 1,000-year-old Minhag, ignoring it should not be taken lightly.